# Splunk Enterprise "WARNING: Server Certificate Hostname Validation is disabled" Issue

Tags: certificate, upgrade, splunk

I'm facing an issue after upgrading the Splunk Enterprise version from 8.2 to 9.0.4.1 about

> WARNING: Server Certificate Hostname Validation is disabled

Some articles said I need to add `cliVerifyServerName = false` in server.conf but the issue is still there.

but after I changed `cliVerifyServerName = true` and restart the splunkd, I'm facing another issue

> ERROR: certificate validation: self signed certificate

How to fix this issue?

Comment: It says it's a warning... so does it actually cause an issue?

Comment: Instead of asking the [same question again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76011764/4418), please show what you're tried already

Answer (score 0):

Splunk is trying to push sites toward more security.  This is one example of that.  They want us to use TLS for all communications and use certificates signed by a CA.

There are two fixes for this problem.  Either set `cliVerifyServerName=false` and ignore the warning or set `cliVerifyServerName=true` and install certificates from a known CA.

Comment: may I know how to install the certificates from a known CA?

Comment: The process for obtaining certificates varies with the CA, but installation process is the same.  Edit $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/server.conf to specify the certificate info.  See the "Securing Splunk Enterprise" manual at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.4/Security/ConfigureandinstallcertificatesforLogObserver#Obtain_a_certificate_from_a_third_party_to_secure_the_Splunk_Enterprise_management_port

Comment: I configured the cliVerifyServerName as suggested.

**
[sslConfig]
cliVerifyServerName=true
sslRootCAPath=/opt/splunk/etc/auth/splunkweb/ourcertificate.crt
**

But after that I restart the splunkd, when I try to run splunk show shcluster-status I got an error below.

**
ERROR: certificate validation: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Encountered some errors while trying to obtain shcluster status.
Couldn't complete HTTP request: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
**

What do I need to solve the issue?

Comment: The solution is to remove the self-signed certificate from the certificate chain, but I recommend setting `cliVerifyServerName=false`.